# Postgres SQL Grouping By column value inside of Case statment

Tags: postgresql

t1:

| AccountName | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-06-30 | 2 |
| A2 | 2022-06-30 | 1 |
| A3 | 2022-06-30 |  |
| A1 | 2022-07-31 | 4 |
| A2 | 2022-07-31 | 5 |
| A3 | 2022-07-31 |  |

I want to do a transformation on this table such that I fill in the "Amount" column of all rows with account name 'A3' and lets say that for each month group the 'A3' -"Amount" value is equal to (the 'A1' 'Amount' column  + the 'A2' 'Amount' column), so the expected result table is:

| AccountName | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-06-30 | 2 |
| A2 | 2022-06-30 | 1 |
| A3 | 2022-06-30 | 3 |
| A1 | 2022-07-31 | 4 |
| A2 | 2022-07-31 | 5 |
| A3 | 2022-07-31 | 9 |

The only way I can think of solving this is using multiple CTE's to separate each 'Date' value and using a case statements with multiple selects to get these values the using a union at the end:

```
with d1 as (
select * 
from t1 
WHERE Date = '2022-06-30'),

c1 as (
SELECT 
"AccountName", 
"Date",
Case WHEN "AccountName" = 'A3' 
THEN (SELECT "Amount" FROM t1 WHERE "AccountName" = 'A1') + 
(SELECT "Amount" FROM t1 WHERE AccountName = 'A2')
ELSE "Amount" END AS "Amount"
FROM d1),

d2 as (
select * 
from t1 
WHERE Date = '2022-07-31'),

c2 as (
SELECT 
"AccountName", 
"Date",
Case WHEN "AccountName" = 'A3' 
THEN (SELECT "Amount" FROM t1 WHERE "AccountName" = 'A1') + 
(SELECT "Amount" FROM t1 WHERE AccountName = 'A2')
ELSE "Amount" END AS "Amount"
FROM d2) 

SELECT * FROM c1
Union
SELECT * FROM c2
```

Is a better way of doing this? As i have multiple row calculations based on other row values and on top of that multiple Distinct 'Date' values (24) for which i would have to create separate CTE's for. This would result in an extremely long sql script for me. Is there maybe a way to group by every 'Date' value in the date column to avoid making multiple CTE's for each 'Date' Value? Additionally is there a better way to construct the sums values for the 'Amount' values for all 'A3' rows rather that using multiple selects in side each 'CASE WHEN'? Thanks!

Comment: Is it specifically "A1 + A2", or is it just "all the other accounts"?

Comment: Generally it would just be some operation based on other "AccountName"'s "Amount" values so "A1 + A2", or "A1 - A2", or "A1 / A2",

Comment: Ah so you really have always only exactly 3 accounts?

Comment: Not necessarily, sometimes in the real data set i'm transforming it'll be like n number of accounts that add up to another one, or potentially subtract

Comment: If it's subtract, then you need to do `A1 - SUM(not-A1)` - there can only be one minuend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) for this - no need to hardcode the dates:

```
SELECT 
  "AccountName",
  "Date",
  (CASE WHEN "AccountName" = 'A3'
    THEN SUM("Amount") FILTER (WHERE "AccountName" IN ('A1', 'A2')) OVER (PARTITION BY "Date")
    ELSE "Amount"
  END) AS "Amount"
FROM t1
```

An equivalent query using subqueries would be

```
SELECT 
  "AccountName",
  "Date",
  (CASE WHEN "AccountName" = 'A3'
    THEN (
      SELECT SUM("Amount")
      FROM t1
      WHERE "Date" = outer."Date"
        AND "AccountName" IN ('A1', 'A2')
    )
    ELSE "Amount"
  END) AS "Amount"
FROM t1 outer
```

or, assuming that the amounts of A1 and A2 are never `NULL`:

```
SELECT 
  "AccountName",
  "Date",
  (CASE WHEN "AccountName" = 'A3'
    THEN (
      SELECT "Amount"
      FROM t1
      WHERE "Date" = t1out."Date"
        AND "AccountName" = 'A1'
    ) + (
      SELECT "Amount"
      FROM t1
      WHERE "Date" = t1out."Date"
        AND "AccountName" = 'A2'
    )
    ELSE "Amount"
  END) AS "Amount"
FROM t1 t1out
```

Comment: I'm going to have to go with the last one since sometimes the operations varys for my calculations(ie sometimes i have to do 'A1' - 'A2' or 'A1'/'A2' instead of just a SUM() ) Does this work for PSQL? I'm getting this error: Server error: Database Error in rpc request (from remote system)
syntax error at or near "."
LINE 16: WHERE "Date" = outer."Date" AND "AccountName" = 'Reven..

Comment: I used the window function version of this and it seems to work, but how would i adapt it the a situation where the operation for 'A3' is  ('A1' - 'A2') or ('A1'/'A2') instead ?

Comment: Oh, `outer` is a keyword, I forgot. I don't think you can use a window/aggregate function for division or subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it I think. The amount of rows without one becomes the sum of amounts in the same calendar month. I already combined month and year into a string, but it's probably way more efficient to compare the year and month value seperately but I like how this looks in joins.

```
update t1 t1update
set amount = (
 select sum(amount) from t1 
 where 
   extract(year from t1update.date date) || '-' || extract(month from t1update.date = 
   extract(year from t1.date date) || '-' || extract(month from t1.date)
)
where t1update.amount = '' or  t1update.amount is null
```

Comment: how could you do this only using select statements (without the 'update' command)?

Comment: My first statement is update. It was either a join or a subquery and this seemed safest. Does it work?